# Delay between One Activity to Another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, delay

I develop one application in Android. Which contains so many data (String) and images. string data are come from `database` and images comes from `/res` folder.

In My Application First Activity shows categories of books. Then i select any one of them then jump to the next activity which display all books images and brief description of selected category these all data are coming from database with Query operation and fill custom list view with `ArrayAdapter`. These is working and display all the things which i want.

**but the problem** is that when i click on category from one activity it takes more than 1 minute time to display second activity (Detail Information of Selected Category). So, Here user is stuck. It is bad for my application.

So is there any way to solve these or any Idea to display Activity Loading Process between One Activity to Second Activity ?

Thanks in Advance.

Please Help Me to solve these.

Comment: First of all Change Uppercase to Lowercase text in your question...

Comment: try lazy loading ! just load 10 or 20 items at a time and then when user scrolls down you can add more items to the list.

Comment: Agree with @Ashwani and dont write complex code in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 6):

use AsyncTask as

```
public class My_Game_Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //put a preloder
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            find data from database

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dismiss preloader
                            set adapter here
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

    }
```

call on 
          oncreate as new My_Game_Task().execute();
this will immediately show the next activity and will show a preloader

Comment: I also use AsyncTask for it but problem remains same.

Comment: Why did this get so many upvotes? @SanketKachhela got the first part right about performing the load in a separate thread, but loading *all* of the data is almost certainly not the answer you are looking for. Loading all of the data in memory is inefficient and often unnecessary... you should try to load the data "lazily" (i.e. only load what will be displayed at the beginning, then you can load stuff dynamically as you need it later on). This link can get you started on lazy loading... there are several open source implementations out there too. http://goo.gl/ssTX7

Answer (score 0):

First of all where are you testing the app.. if its on emulator then check it on actual device you would get a idea how much delay takes place actually.!
I had similar problem it takes minutes on emulator but runs amazingly on actual device.It takes just 1 second to display..

Comment: one second is still a very, *very* long time to wait for an activity to switch to another.

Comment: but i dont think its long time considering the amount of images u load.. if u have lets say some 2 entire page background,around 20-30 images to be loaded plus around 40-50 views to load and some calculations to be done on page load it is bound to take this much time ..i know it is actually long time...i am naive to performance enhancement and memory management so for me its ok..but i would love to hear more on it

Comment: It's not a long time to wait for the images to load, but it is a very long time to be blocking the UI thread... there's a difference! It is very obvious when you block the UI thread (i.e. a button remains selected, the entire layout remains in place unchanged, etc. It is much better to have the layout immediately response and then have the images load dynamically one by one... that way the user can actually see the progress being made and is able to manipulate the UI as it happens.

Comment: agreed.! so any way to do that.. ? coz as i said i have many images to load and it is having quite a big impact on memory as well..and does making use of animation.. the one provided by android would help me in any way ? i am using animation to load sections of activity 1 by 1.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one it will make a delay of one second before going to execute any other operations,

```
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
    e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: (1) Please properly indent your code, and (2) You should never, *ever*, call `Thread.sleep` from the UI thread... it will block the entire application!